# How to replicate a query with SQL IN Operator in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-postgresql

I am connecting to a PostgreSQL and using the following approach in a controller but it seems to not find anything when it should return some values:

```
Machine.query('Select * from Machine where Machine.demo_id in (' + ids_demo + ') and Machine.serial_number in (' + serials + ')', [] , function(err, machine) {
    if(machine === undefined) return res.notFound();
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(machine);
});
```

ids_demo and serials are arrays of values. E.g: ids_demo = [1,2,3,4,5,8]

Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Query is malformed. `var query = 'Select * from Machine where Machine.demo_id in (' + ids_demo + ') and Machine.serial_number in (' + serials + ')'` and `console.log(query)`.

Comment: And this is open to SQL injection if `ids_demo` or `serials` are input are taken from request.

Comment: @Sangharsh I don't see the malformation. Can you specify?

Comment: regarding SQL injection no, it is something that comes directly from the backend so I guess it is unlikely to have SQL injection there. Anyway, I am not sure how I would do that to avoid SQL injection, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Create query using this package then pass it to `Machine.query`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format#arrays-and-objects